# moving sr_hand ros fuerte

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to move the shadow hand with this command

> Blockquote rostopic pub /srh/sendupdate sr_robot_msgs/sendupdate {sendupdate_length: 1 ,sendupdate_list: [{joint_name: FFJ0,joint_target: 180}]}"

but it doesn't work.

---

I saw with the command rostopic list -v that there aren't any /srh/sendupdate

> Blockquote
> Published topics:

- /lfmiddle_bumper [gazebo_msgs/ContactsState] 1 publisher
- /lfmetacarpal_bumper [gazebo_msgs/ContactsState] 1 publisher
- /camera/depth_registered/points [sensor_msgs/PointCloud2] 1 publisher
- /sh_ffj4_mixed_position_velocity_controller/state [sr_robot_msgs/JointControllerState] 1 publisher
- /rfmiddle_bumper [gazebo_msgs/ContactsState] 1 publisher
- /rfproximal_bumper [gazebo_msgs/ContactsState] 1 publisher
- /camera/image_raw/compressed [sensor_msgs/CompressedImage] 1 publisher
- /tf [tf/tfMessage] 1 publisher
- /lfknuckle_bumper [gazebo_msgs/ContactsState] 1 publisher
- /sh_rfj3_mixed_position_velocity_controller/state [sr_robot_msgs/JointControllerState] 1 publisher
- /camera/image_raw/theora [theora_image_transport/Packet] 1 publisher
- /camera/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions [dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription] 1 publisher
- /sh_thj5_mixed_position_velocity_controller/state [sr_robot_msgs/JointControllerState] 1 publisher
- /mfmiddle_bumper [gazebo_msgs/ContactsState] 1 publisher
- /sh_lfj5_mixed_position_velocity_controller/state [sr_robot_msgs/JointControllerState] 1 publisher
- /mfdistal_bumper [gazebo_msgs/ContactsState] 1 publisher
- /sh_wrj1_mixed_position_velocity_controller/state [sr_robot_msgs/JointControllerState] 1 publisher
- /r_arm_joint_trajectory_controller/state [pr2_controllers_msgs/JointTrajectoryControllerState] 1 publisher
- /sa_ss_position_controller/state [pr2_controllers_msgs/JointControllerState] 1 publisher
- /ffmiddle_bumper [gazebo_msgs/ContactsState] 1 publisher
- /ffproximal_bumper [gazebo_msgs/ContactsState] 1 publisher
- /camera/image_raw/compressedDepth [sensor_msgs/CompressedImage] 1 publisher
- /sa_sr_position_controller/state [pr2_controllers_msgs/JointControllerState] 1 publisher
- /sa_er_position_controller/state [pr2_controllers_msgs/JointControllerState] 1 publisher
- /lfproximal_bumper [gazebo_msgs/ContactsState] 1 publisher
- /thmiddle_bumper [gazebo_msgs/ContactsState] 1 publisher
- /thproximal_bumper [gazebo_msgs/ContactsState] 1 publisher
- /gazebo/parameter_descriptions [dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription] 1 publisher
- /mfproximal_bumper [gazebo_msgs/ContactsState] 1 publisher
- /ffknuckle_bumper [gazebo_msgs/ContactsState] 1 publisher
- /camera/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions [dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription] 1 publisher
- /depth/image_raw [sensor_msgs/Image] 1 publisher
- /lfdistal_bumper [gazebo_msgs/ContactsState] 1 publisher
- /rfknuckle_bumper [gazebo_msgs/ContactsState] 1 publisher
- /palm_bumper [gazebo_msgs/ContactsState] 1 publisher
- /thbase_bumper [gazebo_msgs/ContactsState] 1 publisher
- /sh_ffj0_mixed_position_velocity_controller/state [sr_robot_msgs/JointControllerState] 1 publisher
- /sh_thj2_mixed_position_velocity_controller/state [sr_robot_msgs/JointControllerState] 1 publisher
- /depth/camera_info [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo] 1 publisher
- /sh_mfj0_mixed_position_velocity_controller/state [sr_robot_msgs/JointControllerState] 1 publisher
- /camera/camera_info [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo] 1 publisher
- /sa_es_position_controller/state [pr2_controllers_msgs/JointControllerState] 1 publisher
- /rfdistal_bumper [gazebo_msgs/ContactsState] 1 publisher
- /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log] 6 publishers
- /sh_lfj3_mixed_position_velocity_controller/state [sr_robot_msgs/JointControllerState] 1 publisher
- /mechanism_statistics [pr2_mechanism_msgs/MechanismStatistics] 1 publisher
- /mfknuckle_bumper [gazebo_msgs/ContactsState] 1 publisher
- /rosout_agg [rosgraph_msgs/Log] 1 publisher
- /camera/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions [dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription] 1 publisher
- /sh_rfj4_mixed_position_velocity_controller/state [sr_robot_msgs/JointControllerState] 1 publisher
- /camera/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates [dynamic_reconfigure/Config] 1 publisher
- /r_arm_cartesian_pose_controller/state/error [geometry_msgs/Twist] 1 publisher
- /r_arm_cartesian_pose_controller/state/pose [geometry_msgs/PoseStamped] 1 publisher
- /camera/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates [dynamic_reconfigure/Config] 1 publisher
- /sh_rfj0_mixed_position_velocity_controller/state [sr_robot_msgs/JointControllerState] 1 publisher
- /camera/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates [dynamic_reconfigure/Config] 1 publisher
- /gazebo/joint_states [sensor_msgs/JointState] 1 publisher
- /thdistal_bumper [gazebo_msgs/ContactsState] 1 publisher
- /sh_lfj4_mixed_position_velocity_controller/state [sr_robot_msgs/JointControllerState] 1 publisher
- /sh_ffj3_mixed_position_velocity_controller/state [sr_robot_msgs/JointControllerState] 1 publisher
- /sh_thj1_mixed_position_velocity_controller/state [sr_robot_msgs/JointControllerState] 1 publisher
- /ffdistal_bumper [gazebo_msgs/ContactsState] 1 publisher
- /thhub_bumper [gazebo_msgs/ContactsState] 1 publisher
- /gazebo/link_states [gazebo_msgs/LinkStates] 1 publisher
- /sh_mfj3_mixed_position_velocity_controller/state [sr_robot_msgs/JointControllerState] 1 publisher
- /sh_thj4_mixed_position_velocity_controller/state [sr_robot_msgs/JointControllerState] 1 publisher
- /sh_lfj0_mixed_position_velocity_controller/state [sr_robot_msgs/JointControllerState] 1 publisher
- /gazebo/model_states [gazebo_msgs/ModelStates] 1 publisher
- /clock [rosgraph_msgs/Clock] 1 publisher
- /camera/image_raw [sensor_msgs/Image] 1 publisher
- /sh_thj3_mixed_position_velocity_controller/state [sr_robot_msgs/JointControllerState] 1 publisher
- /sh_mfj4_mixed_position_velocity_controller/state [sr_robot_msgs/JointControllerState] 1 publisher
- /sh_wrj2_mixed_position_velocity_controller/state [sr_robot_msgs/JointControllerState] 1 publisher
- /gazebo/parameter_updates [dynamic_reconfigure/Config] 1 publisher
  Subscribed topics:
- /sh_mfj0_mixed_position_velocity_controller/command [std_msgs/Float64] 1 subscriber
- /sh_lfj0_mixed_position_velocity_controller/command [std_msgs/Float64] 1 subscriber
- /gazebo/set_link_state [gazebo_msgs/LinkState] 1 subscriber
- /sh_lfj3_mixed_position_velocity_controller/command [std_msgs/Float64] 1 subscriber
- /set_hfov [std_msgs/Float64] 1 subscriber
- /tf [tf/tfMessage] 1 subscriber
- /sa_es_position_controller/command [std_msgs/Float64] 1 subscriber
- /sh_wrj1_mixed_position_velocity_controller/command [std_msgs/Float64] 1 subscriber
- /sh_thj2_mixed_position_velocity_controller/command [std_msgs/Float64] 1 subscriber
- /sh_wrj2_mixed_position_velocity_controller/command [std_msgs/Float64] 1 subscriber
- /sh_ffj4_mixed_position_velocity_controller/command [std_msgs/Float64] 1 subscriber
- /sh_lfj5_mixed_position_velocity_controller/command [std_msgs/Float64] 1 subscriber
- /sa_sr_position_controller/command [std_msgs/Float64] 1 subscriber
- /r_arm_cartesian_pose_controller/command [geometry_msgs/PoseStamped] 1 subscriber
- /sh_thj4_mixed_position_velocity_controller/command [std_msgs/Float64] 1 subscriber
- /sh_lfj4_mixed_position_velocity_controller/command [std_msgs/Float64] 1 subscriber
- /sh_rfj3_mixed_position_velocity_controller/command [std_msgs/Float64] 1 subscriber
- /set_joint_trajectory [trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory] 1 subscriber
- /sh_ffj0_mixed_position_velocity_controller/command [std_msgs/Float64] 1 subscriber
- /sh_thj1_mixed_position_velocity_controller/command [std_msgs/Float64] 1 subscriber
- /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log] 1 subscriber
- /sa_ss_position_controller/command [std_msgs/Float64] 1 subscriber
- /sh_rfj0_mixed_position_velocity_controller/command [std_msgs/Float64] 1 subscriber
- /sh_mfj3_mixed_position_velocity_controller/command [std_msgs/Float64] 1 subscriber
- /gazebo/joint_states [sensor_msgs/JointState] 1 subscriber
- /gazebo/set_model_state [gazebo_msgs/ModelState] 1 subscriber
- /sh_mfj4_mixed_position_velocity_controller/command [std_msgs/Float64] 1 subscriber
- /r_arm_joint_trajectory_controller/command [trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory] 1 subscriber
- /sh_thj5_mixed_position_velocity_controller/command [std_msgs/Float64] 1 subscriber
- /set_update_rate [std_msgs/Float64] 1 subscriber
- /clock [rosgraph_msgs/Clock] 6 subscribers
- /sh_thj3_mixed_position_velocity_controller/command [std_msgs/Float64] 1 subscriber
- /sh_ffj3_mixed_position_velocity_controller/command [std_msgs/Float64] 1 subscriber
- /sa_er_position_controller/command [std_msgs/Float64] 1 subscriber
- /sh_rfj4_mixed_position_velocity_controller/command [std_msgs/Float64] 1 subscriber

---

I tried to use the /gazebo/joint_state with this command

> Blockquote rostopic pub -1 /gazebo/joint_state sensor_msgs/JointState -- header: 
> seq: 661872 
> stamp: 
> secs: 6623 
> nsecs: 82000000 
> frame_id: '' 
> name: ['ShoulderJRotate', 'ShoulderJSwing', 'ElbowJSwing', 'ElbowJRotate', 'WRJ2', 'WRJ1', 'FFJ4', 'FFJ3', 'FFJ1', 'FFJ2', 'MFJ4', 'MFJ3', 'MFJ1', 'MFJ2', 'RFJ4', 'RFJ3', 'RFJ1', 'RFJ2', 'LFJ5', 'LFJ4', 'LFJ3', 'LFJ1', 'LFJ2', 'THJ5', 'THJ4', 'THJ3', 'THJ2', 'THJ1'] 
> position: [0.03547190965753355, 0.5538400351928834, 2.005389129860628, 0.4267874971556589, -0.44972854860797273, 0.49685233929762074, 0.3348771124869776, 0.34957186538770113, 0.1753774756859463, 0.1753774756859463, 0.30652156679436793, 0.3496880730576786, 0.17543354246121723, 0.17543354246121723, -0.30639336666211925, 0.3207001882759526, 0.18617970159071717, 0.18617970159071717, 0.20871679018049782, -0.33739555040647495, 0.2744234731920008, 0.14968358531426462, 0.14968358531426462, -0.12469928878037706, 0.03966197007371708, 0.028151263993568598, 0.017758737283765313, 6.438347474713169e-06] 
> velocity: [80, 0.0003939334221623532, -0.0008670034589908156, 0.0002311582760739393, 0.0005141283598902862, -0.00016909053926950337, -6.801095055064028e-05, -3.958298157486134e-06, 3.667591853069643e-06, 3.667591853069643e-06, -6.885479052072266e-05, 3.300899041901883e-06, 3.0912467390406343e-06, 3.0912467390406343e-06, 6.969314510557275e-05, -6.222720668391576e-06, 6.955900308894906e-06, 6.955900308894906e-06, -2.2804576955235697e-05, -2.1524668576133684e-07, 3.551866948808058e-05, 5.4439542582612755e-06, 5.4439542582612755e-06, 1.0753352181893468e-05, 4.6249390153934954e-05, -1.7912995276020044e-05, -4.2605490544390125e-05, -3.1774485214243504e-06] 
> effort: [0.06135608101494702, 25.203393510444922, 14.287919796612092, 1.4904561167186359, 0.287150287868609, -0.3156920254326293, -0.01115716400609463, -0.015142849349554727, -0.003941047327170967, -0.003941047327170967, 1.2955166734350578, -0.015119649925851953, -0.004023527242887749, -0.004023527242887749, -1.2948279977619095, 1.3058285651006662, -1.0011732980468375, -1.0011732980468375, -0.02997999265876435, 0.011588332125417967, 1.26006226162639, -0.003572051426391029, -0.003572051426391029, 0.00023386045681911198, -0.020158783792026905, -0.007960426626841039, -0.002978830114955802, 0.5152746588879684]

Anyone knows how to move sr_hand in the ros fuerte?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59908/moving-sr_hand-ros-fuerte/) by [phmferreira](https://answers.ros.org/users/4601/phmferreira/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2013-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Sorry about that, we're in the process of updating our documentation/tutorials but they are still out of date, using the old non-standard interface. We tried to now make our code closer to the one of the pr2. This means that the controllers can be accessed on the following topics:

```
/sh_ffj0_mixed_position_velocity_controller/command
/sh_ffj3_mixed_position_velocity_controller/command
/sh_ffj4_mixed_position_velocity_controller/command
etc...
```

The `/joint_states` topic is not a command topic, it gives you the position/velocity/effort for each joint.

Hope this helps.

Cheers,

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2013-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0